# R data.table explode vector column to rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table and a vector which I would like to add as a column of the dt - specifically, "explode" the values of vector to rows of the dt.

**Edit: `tidyr::expand_grid` and `tidyr::crossing` give the desired result**

The code below gives me what I want but it feels like there should be a much simpler way to do it.

**Desired result**

(transform `example_data` to `modified_data`)

```r
library(data.table)

example_data <- data.table(id = c("a", "b", "c"), value=c(1,2,3))
print(example_data)
#>        id value
#>    <char> <num>
#> 1:      a     1
#> 2:      b     2
#> 3:      c     3

explode_vector <- c("foo", "bar")

dt_list <- list()
for (val in explode_vector) {
    temp_df <- copy(example_data)
    temp_df[, new_val := eval(val)]
    dt_list <- append(dt_list, list(temp_df))
}

modified_data <- rbindlist(dt_list)
print(modified_data)
#>        id value new_val
#>    <char> <num>  <char>
#> 1:      a     1     foo
#> 2:      b     2     foo
#> 3:      c     3     foo
#> 4:      a     1     bar
#> 5:      b     2     bar
#> 6:      c     3     bar
```

e.g. it feels like one of the two options below should work but they don't quite. Does anyone have a suggestion for doing this?

```r
# Some examples that I feel should work
example_data[, new_val := eval(explode_vector), by=id]
cbind(example_data, data.table(new_val=explode_vector))
```

**Edit: Extending with duplicate `id` values**

For example, there may be multiple identification keys (e.g. time-series observations) so the primary `id` is duplicated.

```r
library(data.table)

example_data <- data.table(id = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), date=c(0, 1, 0, 1), value=c(1,2,3,1))
print(example_data)
       id  date value
   <char> <num> <num>
1:      a     0     1
2:      a     1     2
3:      b     0     3
4:      c     1     1

explode_vector <- c("foo", "bar")

# A solution using the CJ method
example_data[, CJ(id, explode_vector, unique=TRUE)][example_data, on = .(id)]
       id explode_vector  date value
   <char>         <char> <num> <num>
1:      a            bar     0     1
2:      a            foo     0     1
3:      a            bar     1     2
4:      a            foo     1     2
5:      b            bar     0     3
6:      b            foo     0     3
7:      c            bar     1     1
8:      c            foo     1     1

# A solution using the expand_grid method (simpler in my opinion but requires 
# converting back to `data.table` if trying to stick to `data.table`)
# I also prefer that it retains the original column order.
data.table(expand_grid(example_data, explode_vector))
       id  date value explode_vector
   <char> <num> <num>         <char>
1:      a     0     1            foo
2:      a     0     1            bar
3:      a     1     2            foo
4:      a     1     2            bar
5:      b     0     3            foo
6:      b     0     3            bar
7:      c     1     1            foo
8:      c     1     1            bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expand_grid` from tidyr package.

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

example_data <- data.table(id = c("a", "b", "c"), value=c(1,2,3))
explode_vector <- c("foo", "bar")
tidyr::expand_grid(example_data, explode_vector)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   id    value explode_vector
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
# 1 a         1 foo
# 2 a         1 bar
# 3 b         2 foo
# 4 b         2 bar
# 5 c         3 foo
# 6 c         3 bar
```

Answer (score 3):

In `data.table` an option is `CJ`

```
library(data.table)
example_data[, CJ(id, explode_vector)][example_data, on = .(id)]
```

-output

```
       id explode_vector value
   <char>         <char> <num>
1:      a            bar     1
2:      a            foo     1
3:      b            bar     2
4:      b            foo     2
5:      c            bar     3
6:      c            foo     3
```

---

If it is multiple columns, we may use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(example_data[, ..id_cols], explode_vector)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with multiple id columns specified in a vector? e.g. Say `example_data` contains `id` and `date` (`id_cols <- c("id", "date")`).

Comment: @tbbarr do you want `do.call(CJ, c(example_data[, ..id_cols], list(explode_vector = explode_vector)))`

Comment: I updated my question to explain this better. Let me know if you think there's a better way to do it with the `CJ` approach.

Comment: @tbbarr with the `CJ` in your update, it is using only 'id'?  Do you want also with 'date'

Comment: @tbbar what i meant is `do.call(CJ, c(example_data[, ..id_cols], 
    list(explode_vector = explode_vector)))[example_data, on =c(id_cols)]`

Comment: @tbbarr or do you want the output as in `crossing(example_data[, ..id_cols], explode_vector)`

Comment: The thing is if I take your updated answer it results in 16 rows (in this case) when all I want is 8. i.e. I basically want there to be `length(explode_vectors)` (2 currently) rows for each original row in `example_data`.

Comment: Ah, in fact all I want is `crossing(example_data, explode_vector)`! (the `id_cols` are irrelevant)